# Automapper custom destination property setter

Tags: c#, automapper

How do I configure Automapper for all properties if the setter is being set by a separate method?

```
// My class
class Source 
{ 
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

// External    
class Destination
{
   public int Id();
   public void Id(int value);

   public string Name();
   public void Name(string value);
}
```

It works for each method, but how do I make a rule for all methods at once?

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
   .AfterMap((s, d) => d.Id(s.Id))
   .AfterMap((s, d) => d.Name(s.Name))
);
```

Comment: you should use `Profile` to do configuration. and in each profile you do the custom mappings. give a look at [docs](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html)

Comment: Well, you _could_ use a [custom type converter](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) that uses Reflection to look for a matching method name and invokes it with the value. Though unless you have hundreds of these to do, I'd suggest just writing the mappings.

Comment: @Alexandr if you are starting with Automapper I would advise you to switch to[Mapster](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster)